# How could a known species evolve their vision to have zoom and how would that affect their life?

Tags: internal-consistency, evolution, vision

How could humans (or some other animal species) evolve their eyes in that way, that they have the visual ability to "zoom"?
The conditions are Earth like, and we are talking about known species.
What would be the factors that would trigger that kind of evolution?

It was said in the comments that this was very unlikely to happen, but let's say it somehow did. A species just woke up one day to realize they have this ability.
How would that new ability affect the way of life of that certain species?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Does evolving enough intelligence to build a telescope count?

Comment: @HenryTaylor well that is brain evolution, I am looking for eye evolution

Comment: Since no known species has evolved to zoom with their eyes. The answer would be this doesn't happen.

Comment: @Plexus: Consider the difference between a question starting with "Could..." vs a question starting with "How could...". Wording is important in conveying your request and requirements. Obviously both questions are opinion-based but while the first question asks for an opinion, and "Yes" or "No" would supply the answer, the second question asks for explanation for the answer.

Comment: @Rissiepit good point, but I think it may be too late now, I 'll edit the question to try to make it better

Comment: @Plexus - as I understand it (I'm still new here), putting a question on hold gives you, the poster, a chance to update the question to be more appropriate, and it can then be voted to be opened again. Hey, at least you're asking questions! I've been too chicken to ask. So thumbs up to you! :) I've noticed that the people who vote to put questions on hold try to explain why they have done so, so try use that to spot what you've missed.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the eye would have to be structured very differently.

Our eyes have a single lense to focus incoming light. But to have an enhancing effect you need several lenses with some distance between them.

The ability to "zoom" would require these lenses to be mobile and/or change their dioptre value to still enable the image to be sharp. That's a pretty elaborate mechanism that could not easily just come to happen. So no, i do not think it is possible, and if it is, highly unlikely.